# Enjaular usuario en sftp

Tags: linux, bash, debian, ftp, sftp

Tengo un servidor con ubuntu con 2 servicios, vsftpd para el servicio ftp y sshd para ssh en el puerto 22, ya que quiero que dicho usuario pueda conectar por ftp o bien por sftp.

He creado un usuario de pruebas que se llama "**usuarioftp**"

```
root@debian:/home/ftp# ls -alh
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x  3 usuarioftp ftp  4.0K Apr  7 12:10 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root       root 4.0K Apr  7 12:10 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root       root 4.0K Apr  7 12:38 usuarioftp
root@debian:/home/ftp#
```

Y la carpeta de dentro de esta forma

```
root@debian:/home/ftp/usuarioftp# ls -alh
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x 3 root       root 4.0K Apr  7 12:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 usuarioftp ftp  4.0K Apr  7 12:10 ..
drwxr-xr-x 4 usuarioftp root 4.0K Apr  7 12:40 ftp
root@debian:/home/ftp/usuarioftp#
```

Y en el fichero sshd_config he hecho estos cambios

```
#Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp


Match User usuarioftp
ChrootDirectory /home/ftp/usuarioftp
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Me esta dando problemas el ultimo parágrafo, lo que quiero es enjaular el usuario porque sino cuando se conecta por SFTP ve al ruta /home/ftp/ y puede navegar por el sistema.

Como digo si comento este último parágrafo el usuario se loggea pero si pongo estas 3 linias me da error de conexión.